# Mathematica 9 and later behavior with derivative of a sum

Tags: bugs, symbolic, summation

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

```
In:

D[Sum[Sin[x],x],x]

D[Sum[f[x],x],x]


Out:

1/2 Cos[1/2 (-1 - Pi + 2 x)] Csc[1/2]

0
```

Function f is undefined, but *Mathematica* 9 counts it as constant?

*Mathematica* 8 returns

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's because you take derivative with respect to the local parameter of the sum. Sum itself doesn't depend on x. But in the case of `Sin[x]` it simplifies it first to the expression dependent of x. So it's not a bug.

Comment: @swish so it is good if undefined function is counted as zero?

Comment: Even more, the sum of a defined function and undefined one also gives zero: D[Sum[f[x] + Sin[x], x], x] -> 0

Comment: @Anixx If sum can be simplified then `Sum[f[x],x]` is the same as `Sum[f[y],{y,0,x-1}]`. But without specifying the limits it's not a function, because x is  an index variable not an upper limit.

Comment: @swish so it is correct that D[Sum[f[x],x],x]=D[Sum[0,x],x]? Why you downvoted?

Comment: @swish Sum can have two or three args, this is documented.

Comment: @Anixx It wasn't me. And I can't understand what do you expect an indefinite sum like this to mean. I expect `Sum[f[x],x]` to mean a sum like `f[0]+f[1]+...` to some undefined upper limit, some constant. And when you take a derivative of it, it's of course zero. Or you mean it like `f[x]+f[x]+...` x times?

Comment: @swish No matter what you expect it to mean, you will have to agree that if `D[Sum[Sin[x],x],x]` has a nonzero value, then `D[Sum[f[x],x],x]` cannot be zero in general, since we might have `f==Sin`.

Comment: Please do not initially tag your own post with `bugs` -- this tag should be applied only *after* the community has confirmed that the suspect behavior is indeed a bug.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is just a bug. Especially since it "works" in 8.
You could fix it  by doing

```
SetOptions[D, NonConstants -> {Sum}]
```

first, or by putting this in your init.m file.

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't do that. Even in version 8 you would expect `D[Sum,x] == 0` to be `True`, wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, we are supposed to use lower case letters for variables. Anyway, of course this is not a real fix, just a hack as a reminder that something is fishy in 9.0.0 (waiting for 9.0.1 anyway any day, aren't you, too?)

Comment: Actually, I think I'm just waiting to get version 5.2 back one day...

Comment: Sum[f[x],x] gave an error there ...

Comment: Well, are things better now? Anyway, I'm only kidding about the good old times... they weren't that good, either, I guess.